# QGIS Server Not Rendering VRT Layer that is accessing COGS on S3

Tags: qgis-server, amazon-web-services, virtual-raster, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have deployed a QGIS server following steps in the user manual on an AWS EC-2 instance. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/containerized_deployment.html#docker-stacks

I am serving three layers through it

1. Vector Polygon in GPKG
2. Tiff in Server Storage
3. VRT in Server Storage: that itself is accessing COGs on a private S3 using /vsis3/

The first two layers are being served fine by the server. The third layer is throwing up internal server error. I looked at the logs of a qgis-service container, there is this message `CRITICAL Server[23]: Map rendering error in layer 'va-crmp-dem'`

[image]

I checked access to the COGs (that VRT is referencing to) from the server and the server does have access to COGs  [image]